# (Skip)(Fail) Parse error with stringi

Tags: regex, r, stringi

I was reading/learning [The Greatest Regex Trick Ever](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) where we say we want something unless...using `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`.  OK so I took it for a spin on the toy example below and it works in base R but has the following error in **stringi**.  Do I need to do something different with **stringi** to get the syntax to work?

```
x <- c("I shouldn't", "you should", "I know", "'bout time")
pat <- '(?:houl)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(ou)'

grepl(pat, x, perl = TRUE)
## [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

stringi::stri_detect_regex(x, pat)
## Error in stringi::stri_detect_regex(x, pat) : 
##   Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX)
```

Comment: `stringi` uses the ICU regex flavor, which doesn't support control verbs like `(*SKIP)` and `(*FAIL)`.  They based it on the Java flavor, so the Java version of the Trick (such as it is) should work.

Comment: You can use this trick too: `ou(?:(?!l)|(?<!hou))`. The advantage is that the pattern starts with a literal string (that speed up the research) and lookarounds are tested only after.

Comment: @AlanMoore informative thank you, I couldn't seem to locate a jave equivalent.  I tried `stringi::stri_detect_regex(x, 'houl|(ou)')` but it yields: `[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE` where it should fail on the first element.

Comment: Try with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stringi` module (and `stringr` as well) is bundled with the [ICU regex library](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) and `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verbs are not supported (they are actually only supported by PCRE library).

Since you are matching `ou` that are not preceded with `h` and not followed with `l`, you can use usual lookarounds:

```
(?<!h)ou(?!l)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fH4cO4/1)

```
> x <- c("I shouldn't", "you should", "I know", "'bout time")
> pat1 <- "(?<!h)ou(?!l)"
> stringi::stri_detect_regex(x, pat1)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

I can also suggest another approach here. Since your code implies you want to just return a boolean value indicating if there is `ou` inside a string but not `houl`, you may use

```
stringi::stri_detect_regex(x, "^(?!.*houl).*ou")
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fH4cO4/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `(?!.*houl)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if right after the start of string there are 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible followed with `houl`
- `.*`- 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `ou` - an `ou` substring.

More details on [*Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Note that in ICU a lookbehind cannot contain patterns of unknown width, however,  limiting quantifiers inside lookbehinds are supported. So, in `stringi`, if you wanted to match any word containing `ou` that is not preceded with `s` somewhere to the left, you can use

```
> pat2 <- "(?<!s\\w{0,100})ou"
> stringi::stri_detect_regex(x, pat2)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Where `(?<!s\\w{0,100})` *constrained-width lookbehind* fails the match if `ou` is preceded with `s` followed with 0 to 100 alphanumeric or underscore characters.